# EF Core 3: owned property insert fails when SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**My problem**: inserting an entity with an owned property fails.

I have a `Restaurant` entity with an `Address` owned property. When I try to create an new entity and insert into the database, an exception is thrown at `SaveChanges`:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'RestaurantId', table 'AppRefDB.dbo.Addresses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

**What I did**

My table `Address` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses]
(
    [RestaurantId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Number] NVARCHAR(8) NULL, 
    [Street] NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
    [Zip] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    [Town] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Site] NVARCHAR(150) NULL ,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Addresses] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([RestaurantId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Restaurants_RestaurantId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([RestaurantId]) REFERENCES [Restaurants] ([Id]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

where `RestaurantId` is the primary key and FK from `Restaurant` table.

And

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Restaurants]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Restaurants_TCategories] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IdCategory]) REFERENCES [Categories]([Id]) 
)
```

I defined my property like this in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
    .OwnsOne(p => p.Address)
    .ToTable("Addresses");
```

And I save like this:

```
await _dbContext.Set<Restaurant>()
        .AddAsync(restaurant, cancellationToken);
_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**What I am looking for**

What should I change in order to EF understand `RestaurantId` should get the newly created Id from `Restaurant` table before inserting the `Address`?

I am using EF Core 3.

Update works fine, I just have a problem with creating an new restaurant/address

**EDIT: my model**

```
public class Restaurant
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{

    [Required, StringLength(150)]
    public string Street { get; set; }


    [StringLength(8)]
    public string Number { get; set; }


    [Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string Town { get; set; }


    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Site { get; set; }
}
```

Edit2 : 
I tested a synchronous version as well

Comment: One restaurant can have many addresses?

Comment: Or can you add more details about your models? you can first create a restaurant then add address models to it.if you use ef you can create navigations and then add a property to navigations.

Comment: Not necessarly many addresses. This is a toy project where I try to test some new tools. But this may be a situation and I would like to understand.

But in any case savinf restaurants then addresses is a good solution. The model need each restaurant has an address. The use of owned property is even a way to enforc this feature.

Comment: Nice,Can you provide details about your models?

Comment: I have just Added my model in the question

Comment: do not mix Async and non Async and also you when it make sense...`_dbContext.SaveChanges();` vs `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` futher your AddAsync only make sense if your using db which supports it, aka not standard, but in that case the Async  savechanges become even more important.

Comment: You are right. There was a typo and I used SaveChangesAsync() in the code
I tried the synchronous way, I still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this is probably a bug in EF 3.0
I tested with EF 3.1 (preview) and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have a Class object which has a collection of addresses.

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
var model= new Restaurant{ Name = "McDonald's" };
model.addresses.Add(new addresses{ street="test",.... });
model.addresses.Add(new addresses{ street="test",.... });

context.Restaurant.Add(model);
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

this would solve your problem.

You can add in both your classes

```
public ICollection<YourEntity> YourEntity{ get; set; }
```

or you can use foreign keys.

```
    [ForeignKey("Restaurant")]
    public long RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public Restaurant Restaurant{ get; set; }
```

if you add this in your address entity you need to first create one resturant then add addresses separately

Comment: This doesn't work. It is not different that I did anyway

Comment: Oh your models doesn't support in this way @FrédéricDeLèneMirouze

Comment: @FrédéricDeLèneMirouze I add solution base on your models